# Whether to convert from Task<>.Factory.StartNew / Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll() to async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the simplified code below that gets shipping rates from multiple carriers asynchronously and was wondering if it would be worthwhile to convert to using  an async/await methodology instead and if so what the best approach would be to go about doing that? Or if its working okay now is it really not worth the effort? Thank you.

```
List<Task<ShippingRateCollection>> lstTasks = new List<Task<ShippingRateCollection>>();
Task<ShippingRateCollection> t;

t = Task<ShippingRateCollection>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return GetUPSRates(...); });
lstTasks.Add(t);

t = Task<ShippingRateCollection>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return GetUSPSRates(...); });
lstTasks.Add(t);

t = Task<ShippingRateCollection>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return GetFedExRates(...); });
lstTasks.Add(t);

//wait until all requests complete (or error out)
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(lstTasks.ToArray(), (tasks) =>
{
    //wrap all exceptions into 1 AggregateException
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
});

foreach (Task<ShippingRateCollection> task in lstTasks)
{
    foreach (ShippingRate rate in task.Result)
    {
        ... //display rate
    }   //next returned rate
}
```

Comment: In the code you posted the continuation does nothing. Are you aware of that?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely refactor it to `async`/`await` if you can make the `Get*Rates` methods asynchronous. In your current code you execute them on separate threads only to block the threads waiting for I/O to complete. That's a waste.

If you can make these methods asynchronous, the code might look like this:

```
var tasks = new Task<ShippingRateCollection>[]
{
    GetUPSRatesAsync(),
    GetUSPSRatesAsync(),
    GetFedExRatesAsync()
};

ShippingRateCollection[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// process results
```

Even if you have to work with synchronous `GetRates` methods, refactoring the code to `async`/`await` will simplify it.

Comment: But all but one error will be discarded. He seems to be concerned with collecting them all.

Comment: I changed the code as indicated above which is definitely cleaner; however if I trace the code execution it is running each GetRates call one after the other all on the same thread ID. Within each of the GetRates calls is a synchronous web service call which returns the rates so I assume it blocks at that point and that is why it can't kick them all off simultaneously? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. You can use this code:

```
var fs = new Func<ShippingRateCollection>[]
{
    () => GetUPSRates(...),
    () => GetUSPSRates(...),
    () => GetFedExRates(...),
};

var query =
    from f in fs.ToObservable()
    from rate in Observable.Start(f)
    select rate;

query
    .Subscribe(rate =>
    {
        //display rate
    });
```

The code runs asynchronously and the `.Subscribe(...)` method will return results as soon as they are available rather than waiting for all of them to finish.

If you do want them to finish then you can change the code like this:

```
query
    .ToArray()
    .Subscribe(rates =>
    {
        foreach (ShippingRate rate in rates)
        {
            //display rate
        }
    });
```

Just NuGet "Rx-Main" to get the required bits.

Answer (score 0):

A less verbose version of [Jakub Lortz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4588915/jakub-lortz)'s answer:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(
    GetUPSRatesAsync(),
    GetUSPSRatesAsync(),
    GetFedExRatesAsync());
```